# jQuery fullCalendar - extend buildCellHTML function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, odoo-8

I want to extend `fullCalendar` in a way that it would show special dates names in their respective day cell. For example if user would define special date (in backend) `2017-12-25` and call it `Christmas`, by going into Calendar, he would see `Christmas` word on that cell (let say in top left corner).

So looking into fullCalendar source, I can see that it builds those cells using this function:

```
function buildCellHTML(date) {
        var contentClass = tm + "-widget-content";
        var month = t.start.getMonth();
        var today = clearTime(new Date());
        var html = '';
        var classNames = [
            'fc-day',
            'fc-' + dayIDs[date.getDay()],
            contentClass
        ];

        if (date.getMonth() != month) {
            classNames.push('fc-other-month');
        }
        if (+date == +today) {
            classNames.push(
                'fc-today',
                tm + '-state-highlight'
            );
        }
        else if (date < today) {
            classNames.push('fc-past');
        }
        else {
            classNames.push('fc-future');
        }

        html +=
            "<td" +
            " class='" + classNames.join(' ') + "'" +
            " data-date='" + formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + "'" +
            ">" +
            "<div>";

        if (showNumbers) {
            html += "<div class='fc-day-number'>" + date.getDate() + "</div>";
        }

        html +=
            "<div class='fc-day-content'>" +
            "<div style='position:relative'>&nbsp;</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</td>";

        return html;
    }
```

Now if I would directly modify fullCalendar library by adding this line:

`html += "<div>Placeholder</div>"`

**Just before this:**

`if (showNumbers) {
            html += "<div class='fc-day-number'>" + date.getDate() + "</div>";
        }`

It does add what I basically need, but of course I do not want to modify library directly, I want to extend it. Looking into documentation, I can't seem to find how could I extend day cell content.

And that function is inner function of another one, so I can't access it (or can I?). But maybe someone more experienced with fullCalendar, could shed some light how to do this extension?

P.S. Note I'm talking about all day cells, not events (that has specific event attach to it). I mean it should just check if that day is special day no matter if there is event at that day or not (though actual special dates implementation in backend is in not relevant here).

P.S.S. fullCalendar version I'm using is `1.6.4`

Comment: You might be over-thinking this. Wouldn't implementing the "dayRender" callback on your calendar (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/) allow you to do what you need? If you had a pre-loaded set of "special" dates in a JS array, you could check each rendered day against the list to see whether it needs extra information displayed). Also, consider updating your fullCalendar version - 1.x has been out of support for a while now. 3.3.1 is the latest!

Comment: I'm using the eventRender callback to append html to the event via the element which you can access in eventRender. There is a dayRender callback. Perhaps you could do something similar with that callback?

Comment: @ADyson might try something like that, though I do not see where should I grab those rendered days? All I see, there are some event render functions defined, but I need to catch days, not events. Maybe you could give write some example, to make it more clear? For version, unfortunately I'm bound to that version, cause it is part of another system that uses fullCalendar (it could break compatibility with other system parts if i switched).

Comment: The problem is that calendar object is already initialized, so doing something like `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
});`, would actually create new calendar.

Comment: well obviously, you would need to insert a "dayRender" method into the existing options - presumably somewhere on your page there is a call already to `$("#calendar).fullCalendar({...`?. You just put the dayRender method as a new option into that existing code. You're correct that you don't want to re-initialise the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify cell content like Adyson and M.D suggested. So exact snippet I came up is this (placeholder is just to show it is being changed) :

```
instance.web_calendar.CalendarView.include({
    get_fc_init_options: function(){
        fc_options = this._super()
        return $.extend({}, fc_options, {
            dayRender: function(date, cell){
                cell.children('div')
                    .prepend('<div style="float:left; padding: 0 2px">placeholder</div>')
            }
        });
    },
 })
```

Note that I use `this._super()`. This is implemented for Odoo to mimic inheritance like in other OOP languages.

P.S. this works only for `month` calendar view. Switching to `week` or `day` view, it will have no effect.